# Simulate Moving Timeline with MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mariadb

I'm trying to Simulate a Timeline using a MySQL Query based on the following table structure just an example

```
drop table if exists testing;
create table testing (
   idno integer not null auto_increment,
   date datetime not null,
   primary key (idno)
);

insert into testing values
(default, '2019-08-25'),
(default, '2019-09-01'),
(default, '2019-09-05'),
(default, '2019-09-10'),
(default, '2019-09-15'),
(default, '2019-09-20');
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is retrieving the rows starting from where a given date falls between both dates

For example I can do the following

```
select * from testing
where date >= (
   select date from testing
   where date <= '2019-09-09 00:00:00' 
   order by date desc limit 1 
)
order by date;
```

Which return all the dates from 2019-09-05 and upward, but if I use

```
select * from testing
where date >= (
   select date from testing
   where date <= '2019-09-10 00:00:00' 
   order by date desc limit 1 
)
order by date;
```

Then it will return all the dates from 2019-09-10 and upward, with this date being the new cutoff (which is what I want)

The issue is that it only works when at least one cutoff date has been reached so if I query it with this

```
select * from testing
where date >= (
   select date from testing
   where date <= '2019-08-24 00:00:00' 
   order by date desc limit 1 
)
order by date;
```

It returns nothing because the subquery is trying to do where date >= nothing, I worked around it by changing the query to cater for this but now it is just a big fat mess

```
select * from testing
where (
   date >= (
      select date from testing
      where date <= '2019-08-24 00:00:00' 
      order by date desc limit 1
   ) or not exists (
      select date from testing
      where date <= '2019-08-24 00:00:00' 
      order by date desc limit 1
   )
)
order by date;
```

Is there a cleaner way of achieving such a thing? This way feels very clumsy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a situation where `> all` works very nicely:

```
select *
from testing
where date >= all (
      select t2.date
      from testing t2
      where t2.date <= '2019-08-24 00:00:00' 
     )
order by date;
```

EDIT:

With out `all`, you can use aggregation:

```
select t.*
from testing t
where t.date >= (
        select coalesce(max(t2.date), t.date)
        from testing t2
        where t2.date <= '2019-08-24 00:00:00' 
       )
order by t.date;
```

The key is the `coalesce()` to handle `NULL` values (i.e. all rows filtered out).

Comment: One of the few use cases for `ALL`.

Comment: I have never seen ALL before, this has done exactly what I need it to do... but I don't know why :'D

Comment: If you replace `t.date` with a constant value `1000-01-01` (second query), the subquery should be evaluated only once, and you should be able to use an index on `date` in the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

I think Gordon's `>= ALL` solution is the most elegant - But here are though some alternatives.

You can fix your first query by adding a single line of code:

```
select * from testing
where date >= (
   select date from testing
   where date <= @date
   union all select '1000-01-01 00:00:00' -- <--
   order by date desc limit 1 
)
order by date;
```

If no row does match the WHERE condition of the subquery, `'1000-01-01 00:00:00'` will be returned instead, which is the least possible DATETIME value. In that case all rows will match the condition of the outer query. A disadvantage of this query is that ordering the UNION set will lead to a "filesort" instead of just gathering the first row from the index. However, since the subquery is not correlated (not dependent on values from the outer query) it needs to be evaluated only once. This can though be improved by adding `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1` to the first UNION part:

```
select * from testing
where date >= (
   (
     select date from testing
     where date <= @date
     order by date desc limit 1 
   )
   union all select '1000-01-01 00:00:00'
   order by date desc limit 1 
)
order by date;
```

Unfortunately this only works on MySQL 8.0. (Might also work on MariaDB - But I didn't test.)

You can also use the date value of the current row:

```
select * from testing t1
where date >= (
   select date from testing t2
   where date <= @date
   union all select t1.date
   order by date desc limit 1 
)
order by date;
```

But in this case the subquery is evaluated for every row from the outer query.

If you "read" your requirement as "Get last row with date <= X and all rows with date > X" it can be "translated" to SQL as:

```
(
  select *
  from testing
  where date <= @date
  order by date desc limit 1
) union all (
  select *
  from testing
  where date > @date
)
order by date;
```

See [db-fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cAyoLpzCBXM1pJQuxcVrmt/0)

This one seems also to work:

```
select *
from testing t1
where not exists (
  select *
  from testing t2
  where t2.date > t1.date
    and t2.date <= @date
);
```

But I can't explain why. I don't even understand :-).

Comment: what i really like about these is my stupid brain understands them better, also would these be faster because it still has the limit 1?

Comment: Without tests I can only make assumptions about the performance. I think Gordon's second query modified as I suggested in a comment, should have the best performance. But simmilary fast as my second query. My fourth query can also be modified to avoid "filesort". However - depending on MySQL's optimizer, `>= ALL` might have the worst performance due to *O(n²)* complexity. What you want is: Get the first row as fast as possible using an index and then fetch all rows starting from there. The question is, if the performance an issue at all.